# 2004 Buick Ranier Oil Filter Location

Tags: oil

Changing my oil right now, but can't seem to find the oil filter on my 2004 Buick Ranier V6.  Any ideas?  I don't have it up on stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  If you're under the car, looking streight up at the drain, just towards your legs and towards the passenger wheel.